# React Forms 2 way data binding

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I'm new to react so I'm trying to create a demo project to enforce new concepts I've already learned. I'm Trying to pass a data object up from child component on a button click to parent component (app.js) back down to a child component.  I start with a table component that displays my data and it contains an edit button for each row. The edit button is an icon (PencilFill).

```
function RecipeTable(props) {
    const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);

    const removeRecipeHandler = useCallback(async (event) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`https://react-demo-65577-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/recipes/${event}.json`, {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
            
            setIsDeleted(true);
      
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Something went wrong');
            }
      
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            // passing the boolean isDeleted, which is true when we delete an item from the table to app.js component
            props.onIsDelete(isDeleted);
        }, [isDeleted, props]);


  return (
    <Container>
        <h1>Our Recipe List</h1>
        <Table className="mt-4" striped bordered size="sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Recipe Name</th>
                    <th>Ingredients</th>
                    <th>Recipe Notes</th>
                    <th>Online Link to Recipe</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {props.recipeData.map((item) => (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                    <td>{item.recipeName}</td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            {item.ingredients?.map((listItem, index) => (
                                <li key={index}>{listItem}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>{item.notes}</td>
                    <td><a href={item.onlineLink} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">{item.onlineLink}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <PencilFill className="m-2" color="black"></PencilFill>
                        <Trash className="m-2" onClick={() => removeRecipeHandler(item.id)} color="red" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

When I click the PencilFill icon I want to pass the data to app.js, and than back down to my form component, passing in the data object with the hopes of pre populating the form with the data.

My app.js looks like:

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isDeleting, setIsDeleting] = useState(false);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser);
  });

  // login click handler
  const loginHandler = async (userData) => {
    try {
          await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            userData.email,
            userData.password
          );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // logout click handler
  const logoutHandler = async () => {
    await signOut(auth);
  };

  // function that recieves the recipe object from the RecipeForm.js copmponent so we can  add a recipe
    async function addRecipeHandler(recipe) {
      const response = await fetch('https://react-demo-65577-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/recipes.json', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(recipe),
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong');
      }

      setIsLoading(true);
      //const data = await response.json();
  }

  const fetchRecipesHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
          const response = await fetch('https://react-demo-65577-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/recipes.json');
          if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
          }

          const data = await response.json();
          
          const loadedRecipes = [];
          for (const key in data) {
              loadedRecipes.push({
                  id: key,
                  recipeName: data[key].recipeName,
                  ingredients: data[key].ingredients,
                  notes: data[key].notes,
                  onlineLink: data[key].onlineLink
              });
          }

          setRecipes(loadedRecipes);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchRecipesHandler();
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsDeleting(false);
    }, [fetchRecipesHandler, isLoading, isDeleting]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!user && <>
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <Login onLogin={loginHandler} />
      </> }

      {user && <>
        <Navbar bg="dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand>Milk-House Recipes</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
              <Button variant="success" onClick={logoutHandler} className="m-2">Logout</Button>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
        <RecipeForm onAddRecipe={addRecipeHandler}/>
        <RecipeTable recipeData={recipes} onIsDelete={() => setIsDeleting(true)}  />
      </>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

My form component looks like:

```
function RecipeForm(props) {
    const [enteredRecipe, setEnteredRecipe] = useState('');
    const [enteredIngredients, setEnteredIngredients] = useState('');
    const [enteredNotes, setEnteredNotes] = useState('');
    const [enteredOnlineLink, setOnlineEnteredLink] = useState('');
    const [ingredientList, setIngredientList] = useState([]);

    // change handlers for form
    const recipeNameChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setEnteredRecipe(event.target.value);
    };

    const recipeIngredientsChangeHandler = (event) => {
       setEnteredIngredients(event.target.value);
    };
    
    const recipeNotesChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setEnteredNotes(event.target.value);
    };

    const onlineLinkChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setOnlineEnteredLink(event.target.value);
    };

    
    // click handlers
    const addIngredientHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        // the recommended way to add to an array using set state
        setIngredientList(oldList => [...oldList, enteredIngredients]);
        setEnteredIngredients('');
    }

    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const recipeData = {
            recipeName: enteredRecipe,
            ingredients: ingredientList,
            notes: enteredNotes,
            onlineLink: enteredOnlineLink
        };

        // sends recipe object up to app.js via props
        props.onAddRecipe(recipeData);

        // clearing these after form is submitted
        setEnteredRecipe('');
        setEnteredIngredients('');
        setEnteredNotes('');
        setOnlineEnteredLink('');
    };

    const deleteIngredientHandler = (index) => {
        setIngredientList(oldValue => {
            return oldValue.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
        });
    };

  return (
    <Container>
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <Stack>
                <Form.Group className="m-4" controlId="recipeName">
                        <Form.Label>Recipe Name:</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Enter a Recipe" 
                            onChange={recipeNameChangeHandler} 
                            value={enteredRecipe}
                            />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="m-4" controlId="recipeName">
                        <Form.Label>Ingredient:</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Enter an Ingredient" 
                            onChange={recipeIngredientsChangeHandler} 
                            value={enteredIngredients}
                        />
                        
                        {ingredientList.length === 0 && <p className="m-2">No Ingredients Have Been Added.</p>}
                        {ingredientList.length > 0 &&
                            <>
                            <h4 className="m-4">Ingredient List:</h4>
                                <ListGroup>
                                    {ingredientList.map((item, index) => (
                                        <ListGroup.Item key={index}>{item}
                                            <Badge className="m-2 p-2" bg="danger" onClick={() => deleteIngredientHandler(index)}>Delete</Badge>
                                        </ListGroup.Item>
                                    ))}
                                </ListGroup>
                            </>
                        }
                        <Button variant="success" className="col-lg-2 m-4" onClick={addIngredientHandler}>Add Ingredient</Button>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="m-4" controlId="notes">
                    <Form.Label>Notes:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        as="textarea"
                        rows={3}
                        placeholder="Enter any Recipe Notes"
                        onChange={recipeNotesChangeHandler}
                        value={enteredNotes}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="m-4" controlId="onlineLink">
                    <Form.Label>Link to Source:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control 
                        type="text" 
                        onChange={onlineLinkChangeHandler} 
                        placeholder="Enter a Link"
                        value={enteredOnlineLink} 
                        />
                </Form.Group>

                <Button variant="success" type="submit" className="col-lg-4 mx-auto m-4">Add Recipe</Button>
            </Stack>
        </Form>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

I've tried adding a onClick event to the pencilFill Icon containing the data object and than pass that up to app.js via props and than in app.js create a useState to set the object and than pass that into the form component however, when I do that my app continues to load until its unresponsive and I have to exit the app and reload it. I think I'm stuck in an infinite loop but not sure how to fix / make this work how I want.

Comment: Any help with this would be greatly appreciated